# No qualifying bean of type is defined when running a main method

Tags: java, spring

I've seen a lot of questions about this error before, but no resolution that works for me.

I'm new to Spring, but trying to use the Spring Data for Neo4J library for a project.  I decided to start with a quick spike to make sure I know how everything is working, and so I set up a simple App class with a main method like so:

```
package org.example.neo4jSpike;

import org.example.neo4jSpike.domain.Actor;
import org.example.neo4jSpike.repositories.ActorRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@Component
public class App 
{
    @Autowired
    private ActorRepository actors;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpikeConfiguration.class);
        App a = context.getBean(App.class);
        a.init();
    }

    private void init(){
        Actor michaelDouglas = actors.save(new Actor("Michael Douglas"));
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        System.out.println(michaelDouglas.getId());
        System.out.println("Total people: " + actors.count());
    }
}
```

I have the configuration class setup as well:

```
package org.example.neo4jSpike;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.example.neo4jSpike.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpikeConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory("org.example.neo4jSpike.domain");
    }

    // needed for session in view in web-applications
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
}
```

I'll add the code for my repositories and domain classes if needed, but they're all set up in a similar manner, and are all pretty simple.

When I try and run the `main`, however, I get

`No qualifying bean of type [org.example.neo4jSpike.App] is defined`

I don't see how it's not defined, it's right there, defined as an `@Component`.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Nice that you have an `@Component` but it could as well be not there... `@Component` and no `@ComponentScan` on your configuration class, so it never going to be detected...

Comment: As I said, this is my very first Spring app, so I wasn't aware of that.  Thanks. Turn it into an answer and I'll accept, that got me through this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter if you put the @Component annotation if Spring is not scanning your class package. You can add a @ComponentScan annotation in you configuration class and configure it to scan the package where your App class is located. Alternatively you can remove the @Component annotation and declare a Bean of type App in the configuration class.

Hope this can help.